# How to use a disable a chrome shortcut on a website?

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to make a code editor in html,css and jquery. In the html there is a "save" button and I want to have a shortcut for the button like CTRL+S shortcut but when I did that it turned out to be one of the chrome shortcuts. Can anyone please tell me how to disable a shortcut on the website? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there is no way to do that. The browser takes higher priority than the webpage, and chrome doesn't have a (clearly visible) option to disable the key combinations. You could try using a different combo with a replacement for CTRL (like space), but otherwise, you can't.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @techydesigner. Do you know anything about how they do it on codepen

Comment: @sh4r10 In regards to capturing keyboard shortcuts? Not sure.